# Java Enum Sequence and Switch-Capable

Tags: java, enums

What I need is an enum which allows the following:

Imagine I have an enum called `ANIMALS` with the elements: `Mammal`, `Fish`, `Bird`.

What I want is, for `Mammal` to have more enums inside it like `cow`, `tiger`, `pony`.

It should be useable like this:

```
switch(animals)
{
case Mammal:
     do something specific for all mammals
     switch(animals.mammal)
     {
     case Cow:
         do something specific for cow
         break;
     case Tiger:....
     }
case Fish:
    ....
}
```

If it's already implemented please tell me how to do it; if it is not, help me find a way to do it.

By the way, what I actually need to do is distinguish which `Texture` from a type of `GameElement` I should use. For example an `InteriorWall` has different textures than an `ExteriorWall`, so I want their enums to be different.

Use Example: `WallType.InteriorWall.Texture1`

Comment: How? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

ENUMs are not designed to do what you are asking. 
It seems you want to use classic [object oriented design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_design).
For example:

```
public abstract class Animal {
}

public class Mammal extends Animal {
}
```

Have a look at [composite reuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_reuse_principle) as well.

Comment: This really is the way to go.  Enums are extremely powerful in Java, but basic Object Inheritance can go a long way on its own.

Comment: I didnt want actual classes because my final objective is to distinguish the texture im gonna use, since an element can have many textures (like, lets say, a floor have a default image or a cracked-up one, to add a little magic to the game), and thats why i was trying to use enums to distinguish not only what kind of element it was, but also, inside that element, which specific texture, but since im using openGL and i bind a sprite sheet before all this, i only need to know what kind of texture it is to say its location in the sprite sheet

Comment: This is a better alternative to using `enum`s solely for their ability to be used in `switch` statements.

Comment: In the end my goal was to make it easier for the construction of new elements, lets say a wall, the constructor call would be Wall(X, Y, WallType.ABOVE.Texture1);

Comment: The main reason why class extension would be dumb to use is because it would be an overdo to create extensions based on simply which texture to use

Answer (score 0):

You could make two separate `enum`s and compose them to achieve something similar to what you're describing.

```
public enum Classification {
    MAMMAL, FISH, BIRD;
}

public enum Animal {
    TIGER(MAMMAL), COW(MAMMAL), BLUEJAY(BIRD), TROUT(FISH);

    private final Classification clazz;

    private Animal(Classification clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Classification getClassification() {
        return clazz;
    } 
}

Animal a = ...
switch(a.getClassification()) {
    case MAMMAL:
    /* etc */
}
```

Comment: I suspect the OP is a Java novice.  If I am correct, he/she might appreciate the reasoning behind the usage of the word `clazz`, even if it is obvious to more experienced programmers.

Comment: The reason I am using the word `clazz` is because `class` is a [reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) in Java. If you try to use it as a variable name you will get a compiler error.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification... but this wont do.
My simple goal behind all this was to simplify the way i create new elements in my game. By making a constructor like Element(X, Y, ElementType.SPECIAL.SpecialTexture1); I wouldnt need to create more classes, nor overextend my code. The constructor would build itself solely by checking "Am I SPECIAL, DEFAULT or EXAMPLE? ok, i am SPECIAL, now inside SPECIAL, which is my texture, SPECIAL1, SPECIAL2 or SPECIAL3?"

I dont know, it seemed a smart way to do it...